# How can I cut an expansion gap into laminate flooring along a wall?

Tags: flooring, laminate

A few months ago I had laminate floor installed in a bedroom and it is now buckling. After removing the quarter-round and inspecting it, I see that the installer did not leave a gap between the edge of the floor and  the walls; There is no room for the floor to expand.

Is there a tool that can allow me to cut the floor along the perimeter of the bedroom so as to leave a 3/8" gap.

My circular saw isn't capable, and it would take a long time with my oscillating tool.

Comment: Get the installer back there to do the cutting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saw you are looking for is called a toe-kick saw. Harbor Freight sells one. These days most people use an oscillating multi-tool for this job. It will take longer to do the job with the multi-tool, but then you have a really versatile tool in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

The dremel Ultra-Saw Compact Circular Saw might be able to get close to the wall and do what your circ can't.

[image: dremel circ saw]

Comment: I have this tool and like it, but to do flush cuts, it requires a special blade that's quite expensive.

Comment: yeah looks like you need a raised center blade - Dremel SM600 MultiPurpose Flush Cut Carbide Wheel.